# Tweepy : AttributeError : Status object has no attribute _json

Tags: python, json, tweepy

I'm trying to build a Twitter crawler that would crawl all the tweets of a specified user and would save them in json format. While trying to convert the Status object into json format using _json attribute of Status, I'm getting the following error :

`AttributeError : 'Status' object has no attribute '_json'`

Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: It would appear you're trying to access the `_json` attribute which does not exist on the `Status` object... Share your code so we can see what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

The `_json` attribute started working once I upgraded my `tweepy` version to 3.5.0.